# Firebase Query returned as a Java class

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class `Person` and I'm trying to query Firebase Database by key (which is equal to `subjectId` in the code below) and save the value returned to an object of type `Person`.

Here's my code so far-

```
    private void myFunction(final String subjectId) {
        Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByKey().equalTo(subjectId);  //I need to use query 
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Person newPerson = dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class); //?? How to use query's value instead
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. You will need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get to instances of `Person`. I answered this a few times before, so will find a duplicate.

Comment: That's not my question. I understand it returns multiple children. How do I get it to return the child that has the key that I'm providing as a parameter.

Comment: In that case I probably misunderstood your question. Why do you need to use a query? `mDatabaseRef.orderByKey().equalTo(subjectId)` leads to the same child node as `mDatabaseRef.child(subjectId)`, except that the latter is a won't require the loop I mentioned. If you (for some inexplicable reason) *must* use a query, you'll need to loop. Then within the loop, you can get the key with `childSnapshot.getKey()` as in the code I linked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247560/firebase-get-single-object-from-list-as-snapshot/40249910#40249910

Comment: How do I convert the query that is returned by `mDatabaseRef.orderByKey().equalTo(subjectId)` into an object of type `Person`?

Comment: You loop over the `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` (even if there's only one child node) and then call `childSnapshot.getValue(Person.class`. That is what the question I linked does.